# a file can't be opened in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I can't figure out why I can't open a file which is located at correct place in the file tree.

> **java.io.FileNotFoundException: wages.xls **
>   at this line : `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("wages.xls");`.

Probably a build path error in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this file to a folder located in your classpath, usually named `resources`. You can then access the content of this file through the `Classloader` of your classes :

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream myFileContent = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/directory/file");
    }
}
```

This would work with a project with the following file tree :

- projectRoot

  - src

    - Test.java
  - resources

    - directory

      - file

And a classpath including both the `src` and `resources` directories.

Comment: `WebContent` is a resource directory, but it is specialized into web resources. Just create a new folder `resources` at the root of your project, right-click it and choose `Build Path->Use as Source Folder`